# node.js Mysql connection error

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to connect a Node.js app with a MySQL database which works for another app really well on a remote server with this code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "www.<dnw>.com",
  port: <correct port number>,
  user: "<correct Username>",
  password: "<correct password>",
  database: "<correct databasename>"
});
con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) 
        {
            throw err;
         }
      });

con.end();
```

On execution I get this as a error message

```
/home/akiku/node/dnwbot/main.js:49
            throw err;
            ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 85.25.34.68:3306
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/akiku/node/dnwbot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/akiku/node/dnwbot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (/home/akiku/node/dnwbot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/akiku/node/dnwbot/main.js:46:9)
    at promises.push.Promise (/home/akiku/node/dnwbot/node_modules/telebot/lib/telebot.js:439:29)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at TeleBot.event (/home/akiku/node/dnwbot/node_modules/telebot/lib/telebot.js:432:32)
    at promise.then (/home/akiku/node/dnwbot/node_modules/telebot/lib/updates.js:92:33)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

#### What I thought it could be:

- I checked the port and the host multiple times via SQL Query in phpmyAdmin. They are correct.
- And I enabled in Plesk that **ANY** host can access the database.
- The username and password is also correct.

#### What it should do:

- Obviously just connect to the database. Nothing more.

Do you habe any clues what it could be?

Comment: add port like `port: '8889'`

Comment: @Man: This doesn't work with ' nor with ".

Comment: did you try 85.25.34.68 instead of host url

Comment: @feiiiiii Doesn't work

Comment: everything wrapped with quote  `' '` without `< >` ?

Comment: I used " instead of ', but with ' doesn't it work.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have access to remote server database.Try to connect using workbench or any other tool

Comment: Sorry, I meant 10061.

Comment: And the Firewall in Plesk allow remote MySQL access.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem: The serveradmin blocked the port on a deeper server level which can't be accessed by Plesk.